# Equilateral and One-of-n encoding

Tags: autoencoders

I was reading AI For Humans Vol. 1 by Jeff Heaton when I came across the terms "equilateral encoding" and "one-of-n encoding." The explanations unfortunately made no sense to me and the reddit threads on the Web are blocked by my Internet provider (I use a high-school machine). Is anyone here able to provide basic explanations regarding the two procedures for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check this book with the normalization infos:

https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/neural-networks-using-c-succinctly/

Freely available and gives good explanation to encoding with code example.

Check the part: "Effects Encoding and Dummy Encoding"